# Plone 4: Create New Template View

Tags: view, plone

I have created a new product. I am able to install and uninstall it.

However, I have created a view, callable from an action(actions.xml) but I keep getting an error saying the page does not exist

```
This page does not seem to exist…
```

here is my actions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="portal_actions" meta_type="Plone Actions Tool"
   xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n">

<action-provider name="portal_workflow"/>
<action-provider name="portal_types"/>
<action-provider name="portal_actions"/>

<object name="document_actions" meta_type="CMF Action Category">

    <object name="viewCatTree" meta_type="CMF Action" i18n:domain="plone">
        <property name="title" i18n:translate="">Category Tree</property>
        <property name="description" i18n:translate=""></property>
        <property name="url_expr">string:${object_url}/visual_tree_view</property>
        <property name="icon_expr"></property>
        <property name="available_expr"></property>
        <property name="permissions">
            <element value="View"/>
        </property>
        <property name="visible">True</property>
    </object>

    <!-- more actions here -->

</object>
```

This is how I've specified it in configure.zcml

```
<browser:page
    for="*"
    name="visual_tree_view"
    class=".viewlets.CategoryTreeSettingsView"
    template="../skins/category_customizations/category_view.pt"
    permission="zope2.View"
/>
```

I've also tried adding the @@ before the view name in the browser, but the page cannot be found. The template exists in the skins folder and it does not matter whether I change the above code to point to `/templates/category_view.pt`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your view is raising an AttributeError or KeyError when rendered, which would also cause Plone to display a NotFound error.

Put a debug breakpoint in your view `__call__` and / or `__init__` methods to see if your view is being looked up and called.

That, or your `configure.zcml` is not being loaded at all; make sure your package is included somewhere, perhaps in the `zcml` variable in the `plone.recipe.zope2instance` part of your buildout, or in a `<include />` statement in another configure.zcml file.

Comment: I have but nothing is shown. I don't think it's being called. Besides, I can't see the viewlets.pyc, which I can only guess it is not being called.

Comment: Ah, did you a) restart, b) make sure your configure.zcml is loaded?

Comment: I've restarted it a couple of times, even had to uninstall and re-install it but nothing.

Comment: Put in an error in your configure.zcml to confirm that it is loaded. Then put in a breakpoint in your `__init__` to confirm that it is being found.

Comment: Nothing is happening. I don't understand. I will probably have to tear it apart and start from scratch again.

Comment: 'Nothing' as in: your configure.zcml is not being loaded?

Comment: I have added an error in browser/configure.zcml. The error is not thrown even after restarting, uninstalling and reinstalling the product. I must have missed a step.

Comment: Did you list your project in the [`plone.recipe.zope2instance`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.recipe.zope2instance) `zcml` entry?

Comment: Yes I did. I followed everything exactly as listed here : http://weblion.psu.edu/services/documentation/developing-for-plone/products-from-scratch

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11573/discussion-between-martijn-pieters-and-frankline)

Comment: The tutorial doesn't actually touch the zcml directive, but it should.

Comment: I think the problem is that you miss <include package=".browser"> in main configure.zcml - that's my usual culprint

Comment: That was the problem. I didn't add that in my configure.zcml . Thank you @Mikko.